# Azure Service Fabric deployment

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am doing API deployment to Service Fabric Nodes, and it is by default going to D drive (Temp drive), I would like to change this default behavior and deploy it to another drive or C drive to avoid application loss in case of VMSS deallocation. How can I do this?

Comment: See [this](http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/azure-service-fabric-cluster-data-path/),

Comment: If you could enhance your question (or ask another one) with what you're trying to accomplish, that'd be good. SF doesn't expect you to change this (not a supported configuration). Available/Supported settings are visible here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings#applicationgatewayhttp

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to do this to avoid application loss, however:

1. SF already replicates your application package to multiple machines when you Register the application package in the Image Store (part of the provisioning/deployment process)
2. Generally, if you want your application code and config to be safe, keeping it somewhere outside the cluster (wherever you're deploying from, or in blob storage) is usually a better answer.
3. SF doesn't really support deallocating the VMs out from under it and then bringing them back later. See the FAQ answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions#can-i-turn-off-my-cluster-at-nightweekends-to-save-costs).

So overall I'm not sure that what you're trying to do is the right solution to your real problem, and it looks like you're heading into multiple unsupported scenarios, which usually means there's some misunderstanding.

That all said, of course, it's configurable.

Within a node type, you can specify the dataPath (example [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-cluster-templates/blob/a9c05e05e5bca0e146cfe788b0de112b63656113/9-VM-Windows-Cross-AZ-UnSecure/AzureDeploy.json#L647)). However, it's not recommended that you change this.

```
"settings": {
    "dataPath": "D:\\\\SvcFab",
},
```